# Can I use a helper inside codeigniter route?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, helper

So I have a codeigniter helper that determines wether the signed request is from mobile or not.
and so I would like that my url routes to different controllers when there is mobile request.

for example

```
if (get_request() === 'mobile')
$route['u/a/(:any)'] = "mobile/usr/main_controller/game_detail/$1";
else
$route['u/a/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/main_controller/game_detail/$1";
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short you can't use autloaded helpers and you can't use $this inside a helper. Unlike libraries helpers aren't classes so you can't get CodeIgniter's instance.

However to solve your problem you can however include the helper file.

```
require_once( APPPATH .'helpers/your_helper.php');
```

and so because its already included you can now use this helper's function like get_request() etc..

```
if (get_request() === 'mobile')
$route['u/a/(:any)'] = "mobile/usr/main_controller/game_detail/$1";
else
$route['u/a/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/main_controller/game_detail/$1";
```

and then you can use this now.